# File extension .mdl not accepted using model.save() in Jupyter notebook

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to save this Keras model using the model.save() in my jupyter notebook. However for some reason it's not accepting file extension .mdl and can only accept either .keras or .h5.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,)) #2^3*7^2

dense = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)

y = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10)(y)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
keras.utils.plot_model(model, r".\my_first_model.png")
keras.utils.plot_model(model, r".\my_first_model_with_shape_info.png", show_shapes=True)

#Ref: https://keras.io/api/optimizers/
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

model.compile(
loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
metrics=["accuracy"],
)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)

test_scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print("Test loss:", test_scores[0])
print("Test accuracy:", test_scores[1])

model.save(r".\keras_model.mdl")
#del model
# Recreate the exact same model purely from the file:
model2 = keras.models.load_model(r".\keras_model.mdl")
model2.summary()
```

with this type of error:

[Error for invalid file extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kglrt.png)

Can anyone help me out on this issue?

I've tried doing this in Google Colab and it had zero issues with converting it to the .mdl so no errors there. I want to know why does it happen only in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: The error tells you what to do, .mdl is not valid (what would it mean if it was accepted?)